# How to calculate similarities/distances and conduct cluster analysis from contingency table

Tags: self-study, clustering, distance, contingency-tables, frequency

I have an 18x25 contingency matrix, rows are behaviors observed and columns are environmental features. I conducted a correspondence analysis via the CA() function in R and then clustered using the HCPC() function from the FactoMineR package in R. I got feedback from my instructor to conduct a cluster analysis before doing the correspondence analysis and I cannot figure out how to calculate similarities or distances based on the contingency matrix I have. Any suggestions?

If it helps, my data started with a column of timestamps, a column for the behavior observed at a given timestamp, and a column for the environmental features present. The data were not recorded in relation to the participant enacting each behavior -- many individuals were present during data collection and behaviors enacted in the study area were recorded at given time intervals. This is secondary data analysis on data I did not collect myself, so there are limitations in the data that do not lend themselves to the analyses I would like to run. Perhaps worth noting this is a class project, not planning to publish results.

Comment: You should put in the `self study` tag.

Comment: Thank you! Just added the tag

Comment: OK, just added +1 to attract a bit more attention.